# Cython hello world example is not working windows

Tags: python, windows, mingw, cython

Hi everybody and thanks advance.

I am testing Cython and I have started the simplest case, but I facing an error when I compiling it. Used: Python 2.7, the newest cython and minGW. I have edited cygwinccompiler.py and removed -mno-cygwin lines.

```
C:\Playground\demo_heeds\cython_test>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
skipping 'hello.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'hello' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c he
llo.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o build\t
emp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd
64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Playground\demo_heeds\cython_test\hello.pyd
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined referen
ce to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x93): undefined referen
ce to `_imp__Py_GetVersion'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined referen
ce to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x114): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyErr_WarnEx'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x150): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x18a): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__Py_InitModule4'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyModule_GetDict'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x1c0): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyImport_AddModule'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyObject_SetAttrString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x208): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x20e): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyString_InternFromString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x232): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x294): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyObject_SetAttrString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x2af): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PySys_GetObject'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x2c6): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x2d1): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x2e7): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyFile_WriteString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x300): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyFile_WriteObject'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x315): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyFile_WriteString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x36e): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x3ef): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x41a): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyString_FromFormat'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x480): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyCode_New'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x4db): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x56f): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyMem_Realloc'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x5d9): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyModule_GetDict'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x5f7): undefined refere
nce to `_imp___PyThreadState_Current'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x602): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyFrame_New'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x618): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyTraceBack_Here'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x676): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x68b): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x696): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x6e9): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyFile_SoftSpace'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x707): undefined refere
nce to `_imp__PyDict_New'`enter code here`
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp
.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Any chance you either have a 64-bit python but 32-bit gcc, or vice versa?

Comment: I have 64-bit Python and 32-bit gcc... This might be the problem as you said- Thanks

Comment: Now everything works :)

Comment: For future reference, this issue is addressed in http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows#Troubleshooting If you want the needed files for 64 bit windows you can get them at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libpython instead of generating them as discussed on the Cython website. It is possible to build extensions to 64 bit Python using a 32 bit installation of MinGW, but it is a pain to set up. As I understand it, that is the way that EPD and Anaconda work currently. You may also need to remove the "-mno-cygwin" flags  from the cygwincompiler.py file in distutils to get it working.

Comment: I'm getting the same error but with a 32bit version of Python 2.7.10 and mingw32.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Alright. To avoid having the answer lost in the comments:

The compiler was a 32-bit gcc compiler, while Python was a 64-bit build. This cannot work.